# Unable to return succes message in jquery while posting data succesfully

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling

I'm trying to create a application which posts data from view to my controller, this works. However when I try to use alerts for feedback(succes or error) it's only giving me the error.

HTML:

```
 <!--ALERTS-->
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
        <strong>API has been added!</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="danger-alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
        <strong>API has not been added!</strong>
    </div>
 <!--ALERTS-->
```

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#success-alert").hide();
                $("#danger-alert").hide();

                $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                    var datastring = $("#myForm").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ApiBroker/AddApi",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: datastring,  
                        success:
                            function () {
                                $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                                    $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
                                });
                        },
                        error:
                            function () {
                                $("#danger-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                                    $("#danger-alert").slideUp(500);
                                });
                            }
                    });

                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                })
            })
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddApi(ApiRedirect model)
    {
        var data = model;
        try
        {
            List<ApiRedirect> list = dbProducts.ApiRedirects.ToList();
            int companyID = dbProducts.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyName == model.Company.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault().CompanyID;
            int mappingID = dbProducts.MappingNames.Where(x => x.Name == model.MappingName.Name).FirstOrDefault().MappingID;
            ApiRedirect api = new ApiRedirect();
            api.ApiName = model.ApiName;
            api.CompanyID = companyID;
            api.ApiURL2 = model.ApiURL2;
            api.MappingID = mappingID;
            api.ResponseType = model.ResponseType;
            dbProducts.ApiRedirects.Add(api);
            dbProducts.SaveChanges();
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

My controller inserts the data in my database and I'm returning a statuscode 200 in my controller. However the error instead of succes is getting handled in my JQuery.

Output when posting data:

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I use console.log(data) in my JQuery I'm getting the following output:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddApi(string value)
    {
        try
        {

            return Json("OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

or the following if using ActionResult

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddApi(string value)
    {

        try
        {
            return Json(new {value = "complete"});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

if you add the following to the ajax error, you'll be able to see the error

```
   function(xhr, status) {
       alert(status);
   }
```

Comment: also log the error and return a error message in the exception, better UX

Comment: It's a parser error, i've updated my answer you need to send back json